# Upload img files from local into a slide show, The first image loads, the second does not

Tags: javascript, html, image, dataset

I am trying to make a slideshow where you can upload images from your computer straight into a slideshow. A very poor mans wowslider, so to say.

This is the input field and the HTML:

```
<input type='file' id='getval' />

<div class="slideshow-container">
<div  class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
<img data-taken ="empty" id="first" src="" style="width:100%">
<div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
<img data-taken= "empty" id="second" src="" style="width:100%">
<div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
<img src="img3.jpg" style="width:100%">
<div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

As you can see, I am using the dataset functionality, initially set to "empty" in the HTML and then changed to "taken".

Now the idea is to upload another image to the second slide, then another to the third etc.

The first image shows up, but the second image is not loaded into the HTML element, no error message either in the console.

Also, next to the input element, the img file src is displayed how do I get rid of that?

Here is the JS

```
var uploadHere = document.getElementById("getval");

uploadHere.addEventListener("change", readURL, true);
function readURL() {
var file = uploadHere.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
var reader2 = new FileReader();
var first = document.getElementById("first");
var second = document.getElementById("second");
var third = document.getElementById("third");
reader.onloadend = function() {
if (first.dataset.taken == "empty") {
  first.src = reader.result;
  first.dataset.taken = "full";
}
};
if (file) {
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
if (first.dataset.taken == "full" && second.dataset.taken == "empty") {
second.src = reader2.result;
second.dataset.taken = "full";
}
if (file) {
reader2.readAsDataURL(file);
}
}
```

Here is the link:

https://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/PKZZMz

Comment: So, what's your problem?

Comment: The first image loads, goes into the img element, the second does not. Other than that, this thing runs. I am planning to add some more features, but I first have to get the multiple uploads feature working. I know I could just make a button for every image upload but that is against all DRY principles out there.

Comment: Please update your question with that information.

Comment: I have changed the question and the code slightly, I have tried to make another file reader instance, but does not work either. Maybe I need to reset the input field value every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** fixed at the bottom.

There are two main problems with the loading code here:

1. You are not loading the second image when the reader has loaded, and
2. You are treating the file loads synchronously (second only loads if first has).

The first problem just needs to be fixed by adding a `reader2.onload` event listener around the code that loads the second image. Instead however, see what I did below with a loop, which fixes both of the problems at once and should make the code more maintainable.

You are treating the file uploads synchronously. JavaScript, however, is asynchronous (which is why you are attaching those event listeners), meaning that actions won't necessarily happen in the order in which they appear in the code.

The second image will only be uploaded to the second slot if the first one is done, otherwise it will simply be discarded. What you really want to do is assign each image to a panel at the start, and then upload each one to its assigned panel. This means that the second image no longer depends on the first one being loaded. This method can be used to accept any number of panels in the slideshow.

```
function readURL(e) {
  // Get the files from the input
  var files = e.target.files;
  // The IDs of your slideshow panels
  var panels = [ 'first', 'second', 'third' ];
  // Upload the number of files uploaded, but no more than you have panels
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length && i < panels.length; ++i) {
    var panel = document.getElementById(panels[i]);
    // Use a separate function to prevent handlers from all using the same value of i
    uploadImage(files[i], panel);
  }
}

function uploadImage(file, panel) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function (e) {
    // Triple = (===) makes sure that the variables are of the same type
    if (panel.dataset.taken === 'empty') {
      panel.src = reader.result;
      panel.dataset.taken = 'full';
    }
  };
  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

The input sources next to the upload button are part of the element. You can hide it with the following CSS. The width is browser (and OS?) specific, so if you really don't want the file list visible, you should create a custom element that passes events through to the normal upload button.

```
input[type="file"] {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 83px; /* browser and OS specific */
}
```

Full fix: https://codepen.io/_Billy_Brown/pen/RZrRWj

Comment: Hey this is fantastic work man, thanks. Will add functionality to chose amount of images and the slideshow effect. Just one thing, the var panel from the topmost function always passes a reference to the html id, even when it's a parameter to the second function?

Comment: @ptts `var panel` is a reference to the HTML element itself, so it's the HTML element that is passed to the second function. You should have the `var panels` array at the top level, and it could be populated in another function that automatically generates panels for you. You could also have the HTML element references themselves in the array, instead of their IDs.

Comment: Hm, however, it still does not work. Getting many 404 could not load in the console. But something else seems amiss.

Comment: @ptts I have forked your pen and applied the fixes: https://codepen.io/_Billy_Brown/pen/RZrRWj It's worth noticing that the file input was marked as accepting multiple files, and I added the `<br>` tags because the slideshow was preventing me from clicking the upload button.

Comment: Does this work for you? I am on the current Chrome browser and it does not seem to work. Yes the input elements need a different positioning indeed.

Comment: @ptts It's working for me in Safari, Chrome and Firefox (all most recent) on Mac. Is my CodePen version not working for you?

Comment: Ah yes, it is working, just have to select all images at once from the c drive:-) thanks for the help, was a good lesson.

Comment: I am updating the code, there will be quite some changes. I have added a range input element to pick how many images a user wants to upload. Now I want to add numerical values to the panel array. And create the whole div<div<img<div modules based on the input range value.
Now I am not sure what kind of IDs to set dynamically to the new created elements, the best would be a numerical value but that is not allowed. How would you approach this? So, based on the range input, we create a div+img module, give the img an id which is stored in the panel []. Thanks, we can use chat if you lik

Comment: Ah yea, and where to append the dynamically created modules, I just can't figure that out.

Comment: I've moved it into the chat as StackOverflow automatically suggests: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150479/discussion-between-billy-brown-and-ptts